# crashing application while print NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c

use of string crashing application.
`temp` is Normal string and `strStartDate` is also string from Date.
.h file

```
NSString *temp;
NSString *strStartDate
int status;
```

.m file

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    status = 1;
     strStartDate=[[NSString alloc]init];
    [self stateChanged];
}
-(void)stateChanged
{
    switch(status)
    {
    case 0:
        NSLog(@"%@",temp);
        NSLog(@"Start Date : %@",strStartDate);
        break;

    case 1:
        temp=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"Temp is here"];
        chargeStartDate=[[NSDate date] retain];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY"];
        strStartDate =  [dateFormat stringFromDate:chargeStartDate];
        NSLog(@"string of start date : %@",strStartDate);
        [timeFormat release];
        [dateFormat release];
        break;
    }
}
```

`temp` is Normal string and `strStartDate` is also string from Date.
strings  `temp` and `strStartDate` both allocating same place, both are class variable, and print same place but in `case 0` temp is print while `strStarDate` crashing. Why?

I know this is simple but, i can't understand. Please help me.

Comment: This is just a hunch, but did you mean `dd/MM/yyyy` rather than `dd/MM/YYYY`?

Comment: in the application you Use ARC??

Comment: Above you assign status=1 then how control can be reach in case 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a retain on strStartDate after initializing it with stringFromDate. The result of that call will be auto released so you need a retain to stop the object being freed.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much. But  can you explain little why we don't need to retain temp string. it's working fine without retain.

Comment: @combinatorial but there is no autorelease pool.

Comment: There is always an autorelease pool provided by the system

Comment: You don't need to retain temp string as you created it with a call to alloc which returns a retained object. See the doc and the section basic memory management rules... https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Its happen because in `strStartDate` variable no value stored and it is `nil(NULL)` so when you want to print it with `%@` at that time its not get string value so app crashed ..

try with first assign `strStartDate = @"";` and then print it, it will work..

Comment: strStartDate =  [dateFormat stringFromDate:chargeStartDate]; , op is assigning value to strStartDate.

Comment: @ParagBafna read question, here app crashed at case 0 mate.. :)

Comment: FYK, If strStartDate is nil then it will not crash it simply print (null)

Comment: @Pandey_Laxman sometime when we alloc the string and not assign the value at that time its happen in my some application i faced these type of problems mate just try it dude... first alloc it and the print it..

Comment: In ARC If you simply declare object without initialization then ARC assign nil. if you alloc any object then it contains some address not nil. but the object instances are nil.

Comment: i know mate you both are right i face this rpoblem and i solved it with assigh string = @""; and its not occure in every class but some class something went wrong i think so thats reason to its problem occure mate... hope u understand..